# Limit unix users file access

Tags: unix, user-management, terminal, users

I just created a new user on my server, but I only want this user to have access to var/www/ and all the files/folders inside that.

They should be able to access no other files on the server except those.

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to chroot that user to that directory. I can't give examples right now, but restricting to one directory does call for chroot.

Comment: @DaDaDom if you do that, the user won't be able to execute anything, as there would be no /usr/bin, etc.

Comment: @Michael why don't you tell us why you wan't to do that?

Comment: well, I made a new user so the user can access the server via SFTP. I don't want him having access to the entire server, just var/www/.

Answer (score 4):

The recommended way to do this is with SSH's recently added ChrootDirectory feature:

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/590